# Htaccess File is not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The RewriteRule `^(.*)$ FRAMEWORK.php?%` portion is showing up when I type a non www. Can someone help correct or advise why this is occurring.

I don't what the line is suppose to do. If I remove it the site won't load.

```
# Mod Rewrite
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ FRAMEWORK.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&resource=$1& [L]

# index redirect

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# non-www (non-canonical) to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|staging\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please post only relevant code – all the `Expires` and `AddOutputFilterByType` stuff should have nothing to do with the problem whatsoever, so please remove it.

Comment: Nah, that was most likely too much (I edited it back in). See my answer for problem and solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ FRAMEWORK.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&resource=$1& [L]
```

After that rule is done, a new round of rewriting starts (that’s always the case when using rewriting within .htaccess).

```
# non-www (non-canonical) to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|staging\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So when this rule es evaluated on the next round, the URL-path to rewrite is already `FRAMEWORK.php`, so this is what `$1` captures – and since this is an external redirect, it shows up in the address bar afterwards.

So you should switch the order of these two rules – rewrite non-www to www first. After that’s done, the redirect happens, so no more rewriting happens.

And then, when the *new* request reaches the server, the non-www condition is not true any more, and after that you should be able to rewrite to `FRAMEWORK.php` without problems.

Comment: Cbroe - is there a way to diagnose why a website is down? There is no server error displayed.

Comment: Something happened and now the site is down.